# Rails 6: How do I remove a record, associated through a join table without removing it from the associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `subscriptions` and `orders`. They have a many to many relationship through a join table.

In `Subscription` I want to fetch an order and remove its association:

```rb
Subscription.first.orders.count
#=> 3
Subscription.first.orders.first.delete
#=> #<Order:0x00007ffae18cf5a8...
Subscription.first.orders.count
#=> 2
```

However this also destroys the record in the orders table.

```rb
Order.count
#=> 3
Subscription.first.orders.first.delete
#=> #<Order:0x00007ffae18cf5a8...
Order.count
#=> 2
```

How do I removed the association with an order – that is, delete the row that points the subscription to the order in the join table – without destroying the order record itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the HABTM association by passing the object to `delete` method as below,

```
subscription = Subscription.first
order = subscription.orders.first

# Pass the Order object that needs to be removed from association table
subscription.orders.delete(order)
```